# storing the information from a big JSON file with JS in an offline application

Tags: javascript, android, json, indexeddb

i have a JSON file with 400.000+ elements (26mb file).
something like

```
 [
   {
    "FIELD1":"-38",
    "FIELD2":"12,4",
    "FIELD3":"SG"
  },
  {
    "FIELD1":"-37,9",
    "FIELD2":"12,1",
    "FIELD3":"SG"
  },
  {
    "FIELD1":"-37,9",
    "FIELD2":"12,2",
    "FIELD3":"SG"
  }, ETC...
```

im developing an offline application (an APP for tablet) and i need to find out the value of FIELD3 passing FIELD1 value and FIELD2 value.

my problem is that the file is too big to open it with Javascript because the browser/tablet stop responding when i try to read it.

i tried to make an IndexedDB and pass the information from the JSON so i tought that would be easier to access the information on it but when i try to read the JSON file to store the information on the DB i have the same problem with the memory.

i cant store the information on a Mysql server and use AJAX to read it because the application must be offline.

any solution?

Comment: use `JsonReader` then

Comment: i forgot to say that im using phonegap to make the APP. JsonReader is only for android native, right?

Comment: i have no green idea about phonegap